# Grouped bar chart in Plotly (Python) with high/low bars

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to figure out how to get the top 10 countries with the highest life expectancy and the lowest bottom 10 of countries with the lowest life expectancy, then represent the countries as bars with the high and low grouped next to each other. I can't get them to group (not to mention the bars are so skinny (why?) and that one bar stacks on top of another which throws the whole Y axis values off).

How do I get sets of 2 bars (high and low) next to each other in a Plotly bar chart? I am open to using either Plotly Express or Graph Object library.

Code so far:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ThuwarakeshM/geting-started-with-plottly-dash/main/life_expectancy.csv'
)

# Get the top 10 countries with the highest life expectancy
df_top_10 = df.nlargest(10, 'Life expectancy')
# Get the bottom 10 countries with lowest life expectancy
df_low_10 = df.nsmallest(10, 'Life expectancy')

fig2 = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='High LE', x=df_top_10['Schooling'], y=df['Life expectancy']),
    go.Bar(name='Low LE', x=df_low_10['Schooling'], y=df['Life expectancy'])
])
# Change the bar mode
fig2.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig2.show()
```

The chart does not look right, however.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- there are multiple dimensions to your data.  IMHO **bar** is not really the way to show to continuous variables
- have changed to **Plotly Express** provided a few options

  1. change xaxis from continuous to categorical
  2. use bins to change xaxis from continuous to categorical
  3. use a categorical variable as xaxis
- in all cases have put variables in hover text

```
df2 = pd.concat(
    [
        df.nlargest(10, "Life expectancy").assign(cat="High LE"),
        df.nsmallest(10, "Life expectancy").assign(cat="Low LE"),
    ]
).sort_values(["Schooling"])
df2["Schooling bin"] = pd.cut(df2["Schooling"], 6, precision=0).astype(str)

# same as in question, change to categorical
px.bar(
    df2,
    x="Schooling",
    y="Life expectancy",
    color="cat",
    hover_data=["Schooling", "Year", "Country"],
).update_layout(xaxis_type="category")
# # bin to reduce number of values on xaxis
# px.bar(df2, x="Schooling bin", y="Life expectancy", color="cat", hover_data=["Schooling","Year","Country"]).show()
# # use country for xaxis
# px.bar(df2, x="Country", y="Life expectancy", color="cat", hover_data=["Schooling","Year","Country"]).show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rob, I appreciate your analytic take on things. That looks great, only thing is I have to figure out how to get rid of those stacked bars. They are probably 2 different countries with the same schooling value, but it makes the graph misleading, as no one lives beyond the 150 age. It would also make the Y-axis shorter, so the minor differences in age would be more pronounced. Any idea how to change that?